# WITH statement in JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, database, orm, jooq

I have  query  for MS-SQL  and Oracle but I want to convert into Jooq  .I also trying  somthing like this `DSL.connectByRoot(field)` But I am unable to find this solution . The main issue is that in Oracle  we use clause `connect by prior`  but its not available  in MS-SQL.

MS-SQL QUERY:

```sql
WITH tempTable(ppCode, pCode) AS (
  SELECT DefaultProcessDependent.PriorProcessCode,  ProcessCode 
  FROM DefaultProcessDependent
  WHERE DefaultProcessDependent.ProcessCode = ? 
  AND DefaultProcessDependent.FolderType  = ? 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT nplus1.PriorProcessCode, nplus1.ProcessCode
  FROM DefaultProcessDependent as nplus1, tempTable
  WHERE tempTable.ppCode = nplus1.ProcessCode
)
SELECT ppCode FROM tempTable
```

ORACLE QUERY:

```sql
Select processCode 
from DefaultProcessDependent 
start with  DefaultProcessDependent.ProcessCode = ? 
connect by prior processCode = priorProcessCode
```

Anyone help me please...................

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Common table expressions will be supported with jOOQ 3.4](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/454). jOOQ will also [emulate CONNECT BY](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/668) for other databases, but that won't be available in jOOQ 3.4 yet.